# Changing a qty box to drop down qty in OpenCart

Tags: php, html, opencart

I wish to change the quantity box to s drop down quantity menu in OpenCart on the product page.

The current code for the quantity is below (found at template / product / product.tpl)

```
 <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>"  />
```

Then replace this with

```
<option value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>"><?php echo $minimum; ?></option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
} else {
echo "<input type='text' name='quantity' size='3' value='1' />";
}
```

I get errors with this code. Is the `<select>` html option the best way to do this? Does the code format look correct?

It results in a drop down box appearing but also an error in the qty text box below:

Qty: {{DROP DOWN BOX DISPLAYED}}
} else { echo {{QTY TEXT BOX DISPLAYED"1"}}; }

So the else/echo error appears on the page

Comment: Update your question with the error messages.

Comment: This code works without an error: <select name='quantity'><option value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>"><?php echo $minimum; ?></option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='quantity' size='3' value='1' />

Comment: 'I get errors with this code' - What's the error message?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the error message is? If so, how about "else without if"? Or, "duplicate option values"?